# Loop through custom posts by taxonomy and display the titles in a list, it is repeating 8 times

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have been messing with this for too long after searching the internet through what seems like hundreds of posts and the codex. I feel like I almost have it but am missing something. My limited knowledge of PHP is crippling me. Any help would be appreciated. Also if there is an easy way to add a class of 'active' to the anchor if the corresponding post is being displayed that would be awesome. Thanks

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * 
 */


/* this page is a single custom post page -- single-peterbilt.php */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="row">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="large-10 columns large-offset-1">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="large-8 columns slider">
                    <div class="models text-center">
                        <?php if( has_term( 'peterbilt-389', 'model' ) ) :  ?>

                            <?php // terms for the model taxonomy 
                                $terms = get_terms( 'model', array(
                                    'orderby'    => 'count',
                                    'hide_empty' => 0
                                ) );
                                ?>

                                <?php

                                    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

                                        // Define the query
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'peterbilt',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'model',
                                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                                    'terms' => 'peterbilt-389'
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );
                                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                        // output the post titles in a list
                                        echo '<ul class="inline-list">';

                                            // Start the Loop
                                            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                </li>

                                            <?php endwhile;

                                        echo '</ul>';

                                        // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
                                        wp_reset_postdata();

                                    } ?>

                            <?php  else:  ?> 
                            <?php // terms for the model taxonomy
                                $terms = get_terms( 'model', array(
                                    'orderby'    => 'count',
                                    'hide_empty' => 0
                                ) );
                                ?>

                                <?php

                                    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

                                        // Define the query
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'peterbilt',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'model',
                                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                                    'terms' => 'peterbilt-386'
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );
                                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                        // output the post titles in a list
                                        echo '<ul class="inline-list">';

                                            // Start the Loop
                                            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                </li>

                                            <?php endwhile;

                                        echo '</ul>';

                                        // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
                                        wp_reset_postdata();

                                    } ?>
                        <?php   endif; ?>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb-slider"><?php the_field('thumb_slider'); ?></div>
                    <div class="single-description"><?php the_field('single_description'); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 columns">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="spec-wrapper">
                            <h4>Specs</h4>
                            <?php the_field('specs'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; else : ?>

                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 2):

You've hard-coded the term into the second query. Of course you are seeing the same thing every time:

```
$terms = get_terms( 
  'model',
  array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
  ) 
);

if (!is_wp_error($terms)) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    // Define the query
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'peterbilt',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'model',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $term->term_id
        )
      )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // more code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I couldn't get that to work. However I removed the $terms = get_terms blocks and the foreach statements and now it is outputting correctly, but I have no idea why... Any suggestions on how to add a class of active to the anchor tag if the corresponding post is the current one?